# PDF.js using display APIs in sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, sails.js, pdf.js

I'm a newbie to MVC frameworks. I need to implement a preview functionality for PDF files for a website. And I don't want to implement it the viewer.html way, I need to use display APIs. I went through [Hello world example](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/helloworld) to learn how to use the APIs. But I'm unable to figure out where will the index.html, hello.js fit in the sails.js.

- Should I keep the index.html as a .ejs file in the view folder and embed the hello.js content in this .ejs file?
- Should I write a separate javascript file or can the "get" APIs and rendering logic go inside a Controller as a method?

I tried to get the helloworld example working first. Downloaded the pdf.js and pdf.worker.js into my assets/js/ folder. Kept helloworld.pdf in views folder and made hello.js and index.html into one file - index.ejs. Using routes, I've linked to the view which has index.ejs. But when I click on the link, it throws the error as follows:

```
>     21|     PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
>     22|     </script>
>  >> 23|     <%
>     24|     'use strict';
>     25|
>     26| var doc =PDFJS.getDocument('helloworld.pdf');
> 
> PDFJS is not defined]
```

Where as when I cloned the git repository and opened the index.html as given in the tutorial, it worked fine and shows the content.

I may be going wrong in many places. Could someone help me move in the right direction?

My ejs file which has hello.js logic embedded in it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

    <script src="../../assets/js/pdf.js"></script>
    <script>
    PDFJS.disableWorker = true;    
    </script>    
    <%
    'use strict';

var doc =PDFJS.getDocument('helloworld.pdf');

PDFJS.getDocument('helloworld.pdf').then(function(pdf) {
    pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
    var scale = 1.5;
    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);


    var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;


    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: context,
      viewport: viewport
    };
    page.render(renderContext);
  });
});
%>

</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="the-canvas" style="border:1px solid black;"/>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a long day and many more issues, I figured out some things about sails.js. I faced errors like "PDFJS.workerSrc not specified", or sometimes just a blank canvas without contents.

I did the following to get it to work:

1. Keep hello.js, PDF.js and PDF.worker.js in the assets/js/ folder.
2. In layout.js, move the  tags for PDF.js, hello.js are under "Stylesheets and Preprocessors" instead of "client-side javascript"
3. Make sure the order of  tags are proper. hello.js should come after PDF.js script tag.
   4.In layout.js, define PDFJS.workerSrc as follows:

   PDFJS.workerSrc = "/js/pdf.worker.js"

   between hello.js and pdf.js.

   5. keep your index.ejs file in views and define routes properly.
   6. Remove the script tag for pdf.worker.js from layout.js if it has been automatically included.